# How to pass 'Serial' as an input argument in Arduino function?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, softwareserial

I have one integer value which I should pass through Serial1, Serial2, Serial3, and Serial4 after performing some algebraic operation on this integer. For this algebraic operation, I made a function and input arguments is an integer and Serial number. 
Simple code is given below: *(I deleted every extra part of my code to make easy to understand)*

```
String stringG; int d1; int d;

#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
//Software Serial #1: Rx = digital pin 10, Tx = digital pin 11
SoftwareSerial Serial4(10, 11);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial2.begin(9600);
  Serial4.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
     String  XX = Serial.readString();
    int d1 = XX.toInt();
    Serial.println(d1);
    int yy;
    yy = compareFunction (d1, Serial4);
    Serial.println("Now the final values are:");
    Serial.println(d1);
    Serial.println(yy);
  }

}
int compareFunction (int d, String Serialx)
{

  int ZZ = Serialx.readString(); // I will receive some values from motor using serial4
  //to avoid long code I deleted unnecessary parts
  // I will use ZZ and d values and output will be yy
  return yy;
}
```

As you see in  `compareFunction` I receive value using Serial (it may be 1,2,3 or 4) So I have to pass `Serial as an input argument` in this function. If I can't pass `Serial` then I have to write 4 functions each for Serial1, 2, 3 and 4 which I want to avoid. Is it possible? How can I do it? when I tried with above code it shows error

> exit status 1 could not convert 'Serial4' from 'SoftwareSerial' to
>   'String'

Comment: It's obviously not a `String`. Did you try to find out what type it actually *is*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Serial` object is the end of a chain of classes, each with a different set of functionality.

```
Print -> Stream -> HardwareSerial => [Serial]
```

Since you are *reading* from it the best class to use is `Stream` since that is the one that is the one that contains the reading functionality.

You should pass it *by reference* or as a *pointer* since you don't want to copy the object.

```
int compareFunction (int d, Stream &Serialx)
{

  int ZZ = Serialx.readString(); // I will receive some values from motor using serial4
  //to avoid long code I deleted unnecessary parts
  // I will use ZZ and d values and output will be yy
  return yy;
}
```

By using `Stream` you can use any object type that also uses `Stream` in its class inheritance chain - even things like a WiFi socket connection.

This behaviour is called [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) and is one of the more powerful features of classes in C++ (and other OO languages).

Comment: Thanks @Majenko. It works i.e. now I am able to use Serial as input argument in function. But there is one little problem. When, I used Serial1 or  2 or 3, in comapreFunction, in code`String ZZ = Serialx.readString();
  Serial.println(ZZ);` it gives accurate value like _P214 or P417_ etc. But when I used Serial4, it gives values like _P‚’j_ or _“‚j_. What is wrong with Serial4. I used `Serialx.println("P");` to get current position of motor.

Comment: Well, `Serial4` seems to be `SoftwareSerial` - and it's any one's guess what would happen with that. I never used it. Ever. It's crap. Try one of the replacements, like AltSoftSerial.